# How to play a mp4 file in wx.media

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to do an mp4 player and I am trying to get the module to play a video but at the moment of giving it no error occurs

```
def prueba(self,z):
    self.open = wx.media.MediaCtrl(panel)
    self.open.Load("video.mp4")
    self.open.GetBestSize()
    self.open.Play()
panel = wx.Panel(frame,id=-1,size=(500,500))
self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED,self.prueba)
```

Edit:

When I´m trying the following code:

```
import wx
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,)
        self.media = '/home/rolf/BBB.ogv'
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)

    def play(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = TestPanel()
    Frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

With an mp4 file...

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzhKQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `load` the media `before` the `event` `EVT_MEDIA_LOADED` will fire.
Try this as a skeleton program:

```
import wx
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,)
        self.media = '/home/rolf/BBB.ogv'
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)

    def play(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = TestPanel()
    Frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Edit based on comment
The above code works on Linux.
[image]

If you are using a different OS or if you are on Linux but do not have `Gstreamer` installed, you may have an issue.
There is an option to choose your media backend:

> Generally, you should almost certainly leave this part up to wx.media.MediaCtrl - but if you need a certain backend for a particular reason, such as QuickTime for playing .mov files, all you need to do to choose a specific backend is to pass the name of the backend class to wx.media.MediaCtrl.Create . The following are valid backend identifiers:
>
> MEDIABACKEND_DIRECTSHOW: Use ActiveMovie/DirectShow. Uses the native ActiveMovie (I.E. DirectShow) control. Default backend on Windows and supported by nearly all Windows versions, even some Windows CE versions. May display a windows media player logo while inactive.
>   MEDIABACKEND_QUICKTIME: Use QuickTime. Mac Only. WARNING: May not working correctly embedded in a wx.Notebook.
>   MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER, Use GStreamer. Unix Only. Requires GStreamer 0.8 along with at the very least the xvimagesink, xoverlay, and gst-play modules of gstreamer to function. You need the correct modules to play the relevant files, for example the mad module to play mp3s, etc.
>   MEDIABACKEND_WMP10, Uses Windows Media Player 10 (Windows only) - works on mobile machines with Windows Media Player 10 and desktop machines with either Windows Media Player 9 or 10.

This would result in your media defintion looking like this:

```
self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)
```

for example.